# How to disable on-screen keyboard in my touchscreen laptop?

Tags: keyboard, laptop, asus, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I have a Laptop which supports touchscreen, and since I moved to Ubuntu, there is some on-screen keyboard popup which is very annoying. Every time I touch a text-filling form, the keyboard shows up. I don't even need it as I have a keyboard. I tried to disable it from Universal Access, but it was off by default. Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running Ubuntu 20.04, just open *Settings* -> *Universal Access* and switch off the *Onscreen-Keyboard* option there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question said "I tried to disable it from Universal Access, but it was off by default".